# Spring @Transactional + AspectJ Compile Time Weaving does not work

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions, compile-time-weaving

I have a bunch of methods that are marked with @Transactional annotation and then they do self-invocation and some of the methods are private, so I want to use AspectJ flavour of transaction management with Spring.

I am compiling my code with `aspectj-maven-plugin` version 1.11:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <proc>none</proc>
                    <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                    <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>


                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>


                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <basedir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</basedir>
                        </source>
                        <source>
                            <basedir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/delombok</basedir>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                    <testSources>
                        <source>
                            <basedir>
                                ${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/delombok
                            </basedir>
                        </source>
                    </testSources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The compile part works fine and I see my classes being woven in the logs and I can also see that in the class files: a bunch of `...$AjcClosure...` classes.

But then, my maven script is executing integration tests (which are spring boot tests) using maven `surefire` plugin and the tests that are meant to verify if the transaction is being rollbacked in case an exception is being thrown, are failing.

Here is my `@Configuration` file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class MyAppConfig {

// some beans not related to persistence

}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to configure CTW I had to configure following bean in my config:

```
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        AnnotationTransactionAspect.aspectOf().setTransactionManager(txManager);
        return txManager;
    }
```

Also, my maven file evolved into:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <proc>none</proc>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                    <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <sources/>
                    <testSources/>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <weaveDirectories>
                                <weaveDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</weaveDirectory>
                            </weaveDirectories>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-test-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <weaveDirectories>
                                <weaveDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</weaveDirectory>
                            </weaveDirectories>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need AspectJ Maven or any other type of compile-time weaving tool in order for this to work in Spring. Just use [AspectJ via LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) instead.

Comment: I tried to configure LTW and it never worked for me. On top of that CTW should have better performance.

Comment: The performance of LTW vs CTW is identical except for the longer class-loading time with LTW. I suggest you get LTW working and concentrate on finding out what is wrong there. But I can also help you with CTW, if (and only if) you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub for me to reproduce and analyse your problem. Thank you.

Comment: The reason I didn't want to use LTW b/c I have a datadog agent instrumenting my jar already. If I have several jars instrumenting my app jar there might be unexpected behavior caused by the class loading.