# Why spring transactions dont work when i use EnableTransactionManegment(mode=Advice.ASPECTJ)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, aop, aspectj

I try to use Spring transactions whith AspectJ

**My Project:
**build.config**

```
plugins {

    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    
    id "io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving" version "5.1.0"
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

project.ext {
    aspectjVersion = "1.8.2"
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-tx'

    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt'
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver'
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.3.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-instrument:5.3.2'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**DataConfig.class**

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
   public class DataConfig {

     @Bean
     public DataSource postgres() {
         DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
         dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?serverTimezone=UTC");
         dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
         dataSource.setPassword("admin");
         dataSource.setSchema("public");
         return dataSource;
     }

     @Bean
     public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
         return new DataSourceTransactionManager(postgres());
     }
  }
```

**MainDAO.class**

```
@Repository
public class MainDAO {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    

    public MainDAO(DataSource postgres) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(postgres);
    }

    public Integer getSoundsCount() {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sound", Integer.class);
    }


    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void insertSound() {
        insertAuthor();
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                "INSERT INTO Sound (author, name, id) VALUES (?,?,?)",
                0, "Spring", 0);
    }
}
```

When I call method insertSound from my service it run without exception. **But it should throw exception becouse method insertSound have propogation.MANDATORY.**

[image]

If i change Advice mode of EnableTransactionManegment to mode=Advice.PROXY then i get exception
[image]

But with mode=Advice.ASPECTJ, transaction dont work.

I also try run application with annotation EnableLoadTimeWeaving and set library spring-instrument as java agent but it also transaction dont work:

[image]

[image]

What should i do for the transaction to work with mode=Advice.ASPECTJ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Load-time weaving (LTW)

In order to make this work with LTW, you can use `-javaagent:path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` on the command line in combination with `-javaagent:path/to/spring-instrument.jar` and also add the `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` you mentioned before to your configuration.

#### Compile-time weaving (CTW)

I found a way to make Spring's native AspectJ declarative transactions work with compile-time weaving, see my [pull request](https://github.com/dubdob/SpringTransactions/pull/1). One key thing among other details is:

```java
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(h2());
    // Make native AspectJ declarative transactions work with compile-time weaving
    AnnotationTransactionAspect.aspectOf().setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58869658/1082681) for reference.

When running the application normally (i.e. without any `-javaagent` arguments because the transaction aspect has already been compiled in) after `mvn compile`, the console log should show `Native AspectJ active = true` every time URI `sounds/add` is called. That log line is triggered by this debug statement I added for illustration:

```java
@Transactional//(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public void insertSound() {
    boolean nativeAspectjActive = Arrays
        .stream(new Exception().getStackTrace())
        .map(StackTraceElement::toString)
        .anyMatch(signature -> signature.contains("MainDAO.insertSound_aroundBody"));
    logger.info("Native AspectJ active = " + nativeAspectjActive);
    // (...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you found a way to make Spring's native AspectJ declarative transactions work with compile-time weaving!

Comment: I had some sparetime and was curious, otherwise I would not have bothered. I do not use Spring normally.